# How to setup sbt to use java 14 preview features

Tags: java, scala, sbt, java-14

I have an sbt project with both Scala (2.13.1) and Java files.
I'd like to compile the java files using Java 14, including the [preview features](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/preview-language-and-vm-features.html).
How can I do that?

Following oracle's docs above, I tried to set the javaOptions + javacOptions:

```scala
javaOptions ++= Seq("--enable-preview"), // when running
javacOptions ++= Seq("--enable-preview", "--release", "14"), // when compiling
```

but when I compile a simple Java file that uses the preview features like:

```java
package example;

public record Person(String name, Integer age) {}
```

I get:

> [error] /Users/dvir/learn/playground/src/main/java/example/Person.java:3:15: illegal start of type declaration
> [error] public record Person(String name, Integer age) {}
> [error]               ^

Notes:
I work on Mac with [AdoptOpenJDK 14](https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk14&jvmVariant=hotspot).
My `JAVA_HOME` is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home` .
When using `jshell` I can use preview features without any problems:

```
dvir@Mac ~/learn/playground$ jshell --enable-preview
```

```
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 14.0.2
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> public record Person(String name, Integer age) {}
|  created record Person

jshell> var alice = new Person("alice", 20)
alice ==> Person[name=alice, age=20]

jshell>
```

When I comment out the Person `record` (thus using only standard features from java 14, e.g switch expressions) but keep the `javaOptions` and `javacOptions`, I still get this warning:

> [warn] Error reading API from class file: example.MainJava : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for example/MainJava (class file version 58.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'

When I also comment out the `javaOptions` and `javacOptions`, the java code compile and runs as expected.

Notice that the compiler warning above is like the warning [in this blog](https://blog.codefx.org/java/enable-preview-language-features/) under the title `Forced To ––enable–preview At Run Time`.
Both the warning and the blog suggest to add `––enable–preview`, as I did.

How do I setup sbt to work with java 14 preview features?